# Why Logback/Slf4j logs wrong file and line numbers in Groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, logback

I have noticed that sometimes Logback/Slf4j logs wrong file and line numbers in Groovy.

I have a lot of bad file/line number logs in my Grails application (more than 50% of all logs)

Is there any workaround?

Simplest example:

**logback.groovy**

```
appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %msg \\(%file:%line\\)%n'
    }
}

root(DEBUG, ["STDOUT"])
```

**Test.groovy**

```
@Slf4j
class Test {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("${'Wrong file and line number!'}")
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
23:24:23.894 [INFO ] 0 Wrong file and line number! (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
```

**Example of my grails log output with problem**

```
10:16:44.881 [DEBUG] [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor] -------------------------------------------------- (null:-1)
```

Comment: Perhaps the %file and %line method of logback take a sneak preview of the stackframe and use that?, because the log.info in groovy will be embedded inside a dynamic dispatch, which resolve to using the NativeMethodAccessorImpl. So perhaps the %file and %line does not work in Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when a `GString` is logged (any normal `String` logs the correct line number). I have no clue why it works like this but I have found two workarounds: Either convert `GString` to `String` by calling the `toString()` method (ugly) or use template format with parameters

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
class Test {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def x = 1
        log.info("Does not work: ${x}")
        log.info("Works ${x}".toString())
        log.info("Works {}", x)
    }
}
```